# Compare column names of two data frames. If matching, extract row values

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm currently trying to compare the column names of two data frames (ex. df1 and df2) and extract the values from one of them (df2), if there is a match, to create a new (third) data frame.

Example,

```
df1 <- data.frame(x3=469, x4=465, x7=501, x10=467, x12=459)
df2 <- data.frame(x3="IL_NA1A_P", x4="IL_NA3D_P", x5="PROD005_P", x6="PROD008_P", 
                  x7="PROD009_P", x8="PROD010_P", x9="PROD012_P", x10="PROD014_P",
                  x11="PROD021_P", x12="PROD023A_P")
```

I am expecting the output to be more along with the following,

```
x3  x4  x7 x10 x12
IL_NA1A_P IL_NA3D_P PROD009_P PROD014_P PROD023A_P
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this would work:

```
df2[, colnames(df2) %in% colnames(df1)]
    x3        x4        x7       x10        x12
1 IL_NA1A_P IL_NA3D_P PROD009_P PROD014_P PROD023A_P
```

You simply check which column-names of `df2` appear also in `df1` and select these columns from `df2`.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
    select_at(vars(names(df1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of `df1` column names are present in `df2` you can use -

```
df2[names(df1)]

#         x3        x4        x7       x10        x12
#1 IL_NA1A_P IL_NA3D_P PROD009_P PROD014_P PROD023A_P
```

If only few of `df1` column names are present in `df2` you can either use -

```
df2[intersect(names(df2), names(df1))]
```

Or in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%  select(any_of(names(df1)))
```